# Dict.cc entry of »Rekord aufstellen«

Tags: expression

*Dict.cc* has the following entries for *[Rekord aufstellen](http://www.dict.cc/?s=rekord)*:

> einen Rekord aufstellen = to establish a record
>
> einen Rekord aufstellen = to set a record
>
> **den Rekord aufstellen = to beat the record**

Dict.cc also has the following entries for *[Rekord brechen](http://www.dict.cc/?s=rekord)*:

> den Rekord brechen = to break the record
>
> den Rekord brechen = to cut the record

To me it seems that *den Rekord aufstellen* does not mean *to beat the record*. I posted a corresponding question on dict.cc forum and got a very short [answer](http://forum.dict.cc/?pagenum=16643&hilite=866087&kw=#entry866087) that seems to indicate that *den Rekord aufstellen* can indeed mean *to beat the record*.

So, I'd like to inquire whether the German Stackexchange community also believes that *den Rekord aufstellen* can also mean *to beat the record*.

Comment: There also is *den Rekord **ein**stellen* which means having exactly the existing record score.

Comment: "Den Rekord aufstellen = to beat the record" stimmt für die Fälle nicht, in denen der Rekord erstmalig gesetzt wird, etwa einen Bahnrekord für eine neue Bahn. Triviialerweise ist jede glückende Jungfernfahrt eine Aufstellung eines Rekords. Einen *neuen* Rekord aufzustellen entpricht dem "beat the record" oder eben wörtlich, den (bestehenden) Rekord schlagen.

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand *den Rekord aufstellen* as beating a previous record. Rather, *den Rekord aufstellen* just means *setting* a record regardless of whether a previous record existed or not.

Many records have, naturally, been set long ago so one could only beat them so this semantically might have leaked into some people’s understanding — but occasionally ‘new’ records are up for the grabs like today (the release date of the Nintendo Switch and the new Zelda game) the [record for fastest completion of *Breath of the Wild*](http://www.speedrun.com/zbotw).

Answer (score 3):

Logically spoken Jan's answer is right. "Den Rekord aufstellen" would literally be translated as "set the record".

But this (very rare) case is not how "den Rekord aufstellen" is solely used. Googling "den Rekord aufgestellt" gives a bunch of examples, for instance:

> Unter lautem Gejubel hat Matthias Völkl gegen 10.30 Uhr die Ziellinie überschritten. Schnellen Schrittes und mit 29 gefüllten Maßkrügen vor der Brust hat der 26-Jährige damit einen neuen Weltrekord aufgestellt. [...] Der bisherige Weltrekord für das Tragen der meisten Maßkrüge über 40 Meter liegt nach Angaben von Guinness World Records bei 25 Maßkrügen https://www.muenchen.tv/muenchen-masskrug-weltrekord-geknackt-186769/

Another example:

> Ein aller Voraussicht nach sehr mutiger Mann hat gerade einen neuen Guinness-Weltrekord aufgestellt, [...]  Zuvor hielt der Pole Jakub Przygonski den Weltrekord. http://www.topgear-deutschland.de/133-news/910-ein-nissan-gt-r-nismo-hat-gerade-einen-neuen-guinness-drift-weltrekord-aufgestellt

Due to my jugement, this use of "den Rekord aufstellen" - as synonym for "den Rekord brechen/knacken/einstellen" - is not considered as wrong, but widely used. I think one has to accept, that the real use of the phrase is illogical from a rather strict point of view; but that does not mean that it is wrong, since linguistic rules are arbitrary and not necessaryly logic.

Comment: Your examples include always "neuen Rekord". See my comment to the question, why it matters.

Comment: I think, you are right an I think I missed that subtle point.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes,

> einen Rekord aufstellen

can mean

> to beat a record

---

### proof

I googled for

> ["Rekord aufgestellt"](https://www.google.at/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%20Rekord%20aufgestellt%22&*)

and I found this:

- **Ghost Recon Wildlands: Beta-Rekord aufgestellt**
  Wie Ubisoft jetzt offiziell bekannt gab, haben an den Beta-Phasen von Ghost Recon Wildlands mehr als 6,8 Millionen Spieler teilgenommen. Damit erreicht der neueste Tom Clancy-Ableger einen neuen Rekord in der Firmengeschichte. Kein Titel von Ubisoft konnte mehr Spieler während der Beta-Phase anlocken.
  http://www.giga.de/spiele/ghost-recon-wildlands/news/ghost-recon-wildlands-beta-rekord-aufgestellt/

  *This story says: Some time ago, the maximum amount of beta-players was somewhere below 6.8 million players. This old record was now beaten.*
- **Franzose stellte mit Weltumsegelung neuen Rekord auf**
  In nur 40 Tagen hat der Franzose Francis Joyon die Welt umsegelt und damit einen neuen Rekord aufgestellt. Der 60-jährige Skipper und seine fünfköpfige Crew erreichten Donnerstagfrüh die Ziellinie vor der bretonischen Küste. Er war dort am 16. Dezember gestartet und brauchte für seine Weltumsegelung genau 40 Tage, 23 Stunden, 30 Minuten und 30 Sekunden.
  http://www.salzburg.com/nachrichten/welt/chronik/sn/artikel/franzose-stellte-mit-weltumsegelung-neuen-rekord-auf-231821/

  *This story says: Some time ago the shortest duration for sailing around the world was longer than 40 days, 23 hours, 30 minutes and 30 seconds. This old record was now beaten.*
- **Neuen Rekord aufgestellt**
  Forscher von Siemens Corporate Technology haben einen neuen Rekord bei der Datenübertragung in optischen Polymerfaserkabeln aufgestellt: Dank eines neuen Datenübertragungsverfahrens konnten sie ein Gigabit pro Sekunde durch die Plastikfaser jagen - zehnmal mehr als bei Produkten, die derzeit auf dem Markt sind.
  http://www.n-tv.de/wissen/Neuen-Rekord-aufgestellt-article343303.html

  *This story says: Some time ago it was only possible to send 100Mb/s through a plastic fibre. This old record was now beaten.*
- **Rekord aufgestellt**
  Wenn das kein Meisterstück ist: Angeführt vom überragenden Michael Zeller (378) haben sich die Denklinger Pistolenschützen in Ludenhausen mit dem großartigen Saisonrekord von 1465 Ringen endgültig die Krone aufgesetzt und den letztjährigen Gesamtsieg im Gau Landsberg erfolgreich verteidigt.
  http://www.augsburger-allgemeine.de/landsberg/sport/Rekord-aufgestellt-id36798482.html

  *This story says: Last year Michael Zeller shoot less than 1465 rings. This old record was now beaten.*
- **Pechstein stellt Rekord auf**
  Claudia Pechstein ist seit heute die älteste WM-Medaillen-Gewinnerin der Eisschnellauf-Geschichte. In Südkorea holte die Berlinerin jetzt Silber im Wettkampf über 5.000 Meter. Das ganze nur elf Tage vor ihrem 45.Geburtstag.
  [http://www.rpr1.de/nachrichten/deutschland-die-welt/claudia-pechstein-stellt-südkorea-neuen-rekord-auf](http://www.rpr1.de/nachrichten/deutschland-die-welt/claudia-pechstein-stellt-s%C3%BCdkorea-neuen-rekord-auf)

  *This story says: Until now the oldest winner of a WM medal in speed skating was younger than 45 years. This old record was now beaten.*

---

All those articles tell the story of somebody who has beaten an existing older record in a certain discipline, and in all those examples the term **einen Rekord aufstellen** was used.

Comment: But from your excerpts none of the examples *require* the interpretation that a record was beaten. Sure they were, but the emphasis was always on *setting* a new record. I have no problem interpreting your excerpts in line with my answer.

Comment: The question was, if *den Rekord aufstellen* »**can** also mean to beat the record.« (Quote from the question.) And my Answer is: »Yes, *einen Rekord aufstellen* **can** mean *to beat a record*.« (Quote from my answer.) Nobody wanted to know if such an interpretation is *required*.

Comment: My criticism is that **none** of your examples really support them *can* because they all make perfect sense to me under the assumption *cannot.*

Comment: @Jan: In jedem der zitierten Beispiele wird davon berichtet, dass ein älterer Rekord gebrochen wurde, und in allen zitierten Beispielen wird dafür die Formulierung »einen Rekord aufstellen« verwendet (manchmal mit »*neuen*«, oft aber auch ohne). Somit belegt jedes einzelne Beispiel, dass »*einen Rekord aufstellen*«  dasselbe bedeuten *kann* (nicht *muss*!) wie die englische Phrase »*to beat a record*«.